# Kernel bypassing using sockets

Tags: linux, sockets

Using sockets(internet/Unix domain) is it possible to send/recieve data directly from userspace to network card and viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

yes ... have a look at Open Onload technology.  This is commonly used technology in situations where you want to have the lowest possible latency on IP network communication.

https://www.openonload.org/

Typically used in conjuction with SolarFlare network cards.

Comment: Any guides to implement on my own?